# How to apply actions to generic types in class this is working with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, generic-programming

I am now trying to figure out how are generics working. And I've found this example

```
class SomeGenericClass <T> {

    fun <T> makeSomething(someData : T) : T {
       var localData = someData
       //... doing some actions
       return localData
   }
}
```

And I am now wondering - how we can apply some actions to the generic type passed as param into the **makeSomething** method. Is it possible at all? Can we apply some actions or changes to the someData (not basic actions that can be done with the Any object -toString, hashCode). I thin tha this is not possible, am I right?
Or this example:

```
fun <T> doJob(valOne: T, valTwo: T){

}
```

We cannot apply any actions to valOne and valTwo objects. In both cases we need to extend the basic class or interface and override these methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use methods on an instance with a generic type parameter if you constrain what that `T` type can be, for example:

```
fun <T : CharSequence> useThing(thing: T) {
    println(thing)
}
```

Another way to work with the object that was passed in is to provide a lambda that operates on it, which receives the same generic type. At the call site, this will make its parameter available as the actual type:

```
fun <T> performActions(thing: T, actions: (T) -> Unit) {
    actions(thing)
}

performActions(25) { thing: Int ->
    println(3 * thing) 
}
```

This second example isn't very sensible as it is, but for example you could perform the action multiple times in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: *what do you want to do with them?*

As written, the only thing you know about `T` is that it's some type — because you don't know *which* type, you can't do anything type-specific.  So the only things you can do with values of type `T` are things that work for *all* types — i.e. things you can do with `Any?`.  That includes comparing them for equality (or identity) with other types (or `null`), converting them to `String`s, storing them in collections, and similar.

To do any more, you'll need to know more about what type `T` is.  If, for example, you know it's a `CharSequence` (e.g. a `String`), then you can tell the compiler by giving a type bound, e.g. `<T : CharSequence>`.

Then you can do anything with a `T` that you can do with `CharSequence`, such as getting its length, iterating over or mapping its characters, &c. (as per [zsmb13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54946934/10134209)).  However, the compiler will prevent you from calling it with an unrelated class.

So, with generics — as with any other code — what you can do with an object depends on what you know about its type.

(By the way, the code you quote is a bit misleading, because it has two different type parameters called `T`: one at the class level, and another in the function.  If you mean the same `T` in both cases, then you probably want to remove the `<T>` from the function definition.)